# My GreenTel dongle is not detected in Ubuntu 12.04 LST

Tags: wireless, usb-modem

I have a GT-G20 GreenTel dongle and it is not recognized in both USB 2.0 and 3 ports, Please give me a solution.

Below shown the output when executed "lsusb" command;

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 20a6:f00e  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
```

The device is not even listed.

Comment: @TrailRider : I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If it is a usb error, it may show up in dmesg. So do the following:

- Unplug the device
- Type `sudo dmesg -c` - A lot of stuff will come up, but we are basically clearing the logs.
- Plug in the device
- Type `dmesg`
- Look at the logs for any errors that may help you. They are usually self explanatory. If not, edit your post to include them.

**Edit based on user comment**

Given that you commented that no errors occurred, I will assume you mean no output after clearing the logs. In that case, I would speculate that you have a hardware issue with the dongle. Try it on another computer and verify that it works correctly. If the dongle works on another computer, check the USB ports with some other usb device to make sure they work correctly.

Comment: I can not find any errors in the output